# Resident instance doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-app-engine

Following my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585558/frontend-instances-warmups-although-idle-instance-is-defined):

Here's a screenshot of my billing-enable appengine console:

[image]

As you can see, I have a resident instance, but all requests are not routed to it, and instead a dynamic instance is loaded and gets all the traffic. Either I'm not getting the concept of Resident instances correctly, or this is ridiculous.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAE Starting dynamic instance to serve requests instead of using idle resident instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340530/gae-starting-dynamic-instance-to-serve-requests-instead-of-using-idle-resident-i)

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, resident instances are for times when no other instances (f. e. dynamic) are available (busy, no one started). They are the buffer between full utilization and new (dynamic) instances available. If every dynamic instance is at its limit (or no one available), the app engine needs some time to start new instances. In this time the resident instance is getting new requests so that your service is not getting busy for the users (and/or to decrease service response time).
A resident instance with low usage will cost you as much as one with heavy usage.

Comment: Thanks @da_re. What you're saying makes a lot of sense, however, it still doesn't explain my previous question (I shared a link in the top of my post - in short - even though I had a resident instance running, AppEngine chose to start new instances and still no traffic was sent to the resident).

Comment: We GAE users can't see the algo of the GAE :) . So nobody can answer your question correctly. If you want clarification, contact the GAE support or create an issue at the GAE bugtracker. But it seems that this behavior is absolutely correct, because the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings) says _... App Engine keeps idle instances in reserve, it is unlikely that requests will enter the pending queue except in exceptionally high load spikes ..._ . Resident instances are only for high load spikes. The pending queue starts new instances.

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  My resident instance doesn't get hit at all -- even when I have 1 resident and 1 dynamic instance running, I'm still seeing high load times while I wait for a 2nd dynamic to startup.