# Google app engine load balancing does not seem to be working well

Tags: python, google-app-engine, load-balancing

I already read this:
[google app engine load balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800079/google-app-engine-load-balancing)
and saw the video in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJp6hmASstQ.

I have a paid app with the follow configuration:

```
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
min_idle_instances: 1
max_idle_instances: 4
max_pending_latency: 200ms
```

When I looked in the "instances" tab in the app's admin I see I have 2 dynamic servers working (im not referring to the resident in this question), one handles most of the traffic, and the other one, for more than 10 minutes, does not get almost anything (as you can see in the image). I also checked and the 10 apis which it did handle, were handled very fast and no other api kept it working for long time.

This details are from the most "silent" period of the day. but when we have a big traffic its getting worse, the latency is rising and apis which should run at around 100ms, run at around 800ms which is really bad for us.

Should i maybe configure the app differently? why the load balancing does not split the work if it has more than one server working?

[image]

Comment: There is another setting that specifies latency. Lower it So the other instances will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/ there is only "max_pending_latency" and "min_pending_latency", which as far as i know only affect the decision if another instance should be started. am i wrong?

Comment: It does affect if another instance is started but i think it might also affect balancing

Comment: Ok I tried to reduce the "max_pending_latency" to 50ms, unfortunately this is not making any change. any other idea?

Comment: As a quick fix kill that instance from the admin panel. See if the problem comes back.

Comment: It's long gone. to be honest, I think, from looking at the logs, by reducing it app engine having hard time to maintain stabilty and spin instances on and off.