# Round Robin for VM Load balancing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, load-balancing, round-robin

I have a project in java with Google App Engine and I created 2 VM in Google Cloud Console. I want to implement Round Robin algorithm to balance my traffic between my instances but I can't figure out how. I found many implementations of Round Robin but I don't know how to map them to balance between my virtual machines. If anyone could help me with some code in java, it would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800079/google-app-engine-load-balancing

Comment: What do you mean by "I created 2 VM in Google Cloud Console"? Did you setup an app with manual scaling that has 2 instances? Or are you using Google Compute Engine VMs?